# googleスプレッドシートでArrayformula、IFS、FIND関数を併用した数式の書き方についての質問

Tags: google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートで
Aのセルに「リンゴ」という文字があればBのセルに1を、同じく「バナナ」なら2を、「ミカン」なら3と表示させ、それを以下のセル全てに適用させたいです。

Arrayformula、IFS、FIND関数を使ってその数式を作ろうとしているのですが、うまくいかずにおります。

式の書き方が間違っているのだろうと思うのですが、よろしければ正しい書き方を教えていただけないでしょうか？あるいは、別の方法があればぜひご教示いただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

## 回答

`IFS`は使っていませんが、以下の式で実現できます。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1:A)),"",3),2),1))
```

`FIND`は文字列が見つからなかったとき`#VALUE!`を返すのでエラー判定に`ISERR`を使いました。

`IFS`は使ったことがなかったので`IF`を使いました。

## 作り方

出来上がった式は長くて修正が難しいです。
機能追加や変更する場合は作り直した方が簡単な場合があるので、作り方を紹介します。

### 1.最初に基本的な式を作ります。

対象となる文字列が見つかった場合は所定の値を返し、見つからない場合は999を返す式です。

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1)),999,1)
=IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1)),999,2)
=IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1)),999,3)
```

### 2.基本的な式を組み合わせます。

最初の式の999を次の式で置き換えます。

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1)),999,2),1)
```

対象となる文字列が見つかった場合は所定の値を返し、見つからない場合は、組み込んだ式の結果を返す式になります。

同様のやり方で、その次の式を組み込みます。

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1)),IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1)),999,3),2),1)
```

### 3.ARRAYFORMULAを適用します。

ARRAYFORMULA()を適用します。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1)),IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1)),999,3),2),1))
```

適用範囲をA列すべてのセルとします。※`A1`を`A1:A`に置き換えます。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1:A)),999,3),2),1))
```

999を空文字列に置き換えます。これで出来上がり。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERR(FIND("リンゴ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("バナナ",A1:A)),IF(ISERR(FIND("ミカン",A1:A)),"",3),2),1))
```